how to correctly set the upper limit for my cpus clock speed
I want to limit my CPU clock speed, but it ignores all the settings I apply. I tried using cpufreq and cpupower and the following commands:
sudo sh -c 'echo 1500000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'
sudo sh -c 'echo 1500000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'
sudo sh -c 'echo 1500000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'
sudo sh -c 'echo 1500000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'

I've tried all governors, but it still goes over the limit I set.
it was working fine with windows 10 (by setting the maximum state to 60-70%)
cpu: i5-2410m

Your shell command should have worked, but maybe something else in the backgroung is changing it back. Have a look, and let us know, grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq and show us the actual CPU frequency, grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq. And show us which CPU frequency scaling driver, grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver. And it's details, grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/* if it is the intel_pstate driver, for example.

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
1500000 (all cores)
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_cpufreq (all cores)
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
max_perf_pct: 100
min_perf_pct: 27
no_turbo: 0
num_pstates: 22
status: passive
turbo_pct: 28

its using the intel_cpufreq scaling driver

Everything looks fine for a max CPU frequency of 1.5 GHz. I made a mistake in my comment for what are you actually seeing? It should be grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq

vaio@vaio-vpcca15fa:~$  grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
grep: cat: No such file or directory
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:798743
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:1078542
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:851213
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:1229554
vaio@vaio-vpcca15fa:~$

it says that its max frequency is 1.5Ghz. but when there is actual load it acts like if there is no limit. i checked grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq while there is load. it still says 1500000

running grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq while under load:
vaio@vaio-vpcca15fa:~$ grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
grep: cat: No such file or directory
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:2693895
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:2693751
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:2693880
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:2693880

try this: echo 51 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct. The two methods for setting the max CPU frequency are supposed to be coupled, but for some kernel versions they weren't. What kernel version?

echo 51 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct doesnt work. should i change my kernel?

my kernel version is 6.8.0-47-generic

just upgraded to 24.10 with the 6.11 kernel. still nothing works.

I am running out of ideas. As far as I can determine, your maximum CPU frequency should be limited to what you have asked for.

maybe i forgot to restart it after updating because i tried it today and it WORKED PERFECTLY!. thank you SO MUCH for the help. i can finally browse peacefully without my laptop cosplaying as a desktop furnace
